# Проблема с телепортом в Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Проблема в том, что при вхождении в коллайдер телепорта персонаж телепортируется, но пропадает, и его не видно. В самом Unity в поле спавн телепорта объект я добавил. Код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Teleport : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject spawnTeleport;

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
      collision.gameObject.transform.position = spawnTeleport.gameObject.transform.position;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По вашему коду, телепортация выполняется, когда персонаж вступает в коллизию с объектом, у которого висит скрипт Teleport. Если персонаж пропадает, то скорее всего это связано с тем, что его не видно. Чтобы решить эту проблему, нужно проверить, что у персонажа и объекта спавна телепорта висит компонент `SpriteRenderer` и установлено свойство `enabled` в `true`. Также стоит проверить, что у камеры висит компонент `Camera`, и установлено свойство `enabled` в `true`.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Teleport : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject spawnTeleport;

    private void Start()
    {
        // Проверяем, что у персонажа есть компонент SpriteRenderer
        if (GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>() == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("У персонажа нет компонента SpriteRenderer");
        }

        // Проверяем, что у объекта спавна телепорта есть компонент SpriteRenderer
        if (spawnTeleport.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>() == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("У объекта спавна телепорта нет компонента SpriteRenderer");
        }

        // Проверяем, что у камеры есть компонент Camera
        if (Camera.main.GetComponent<Camera>() == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("У камеры нет компонента Camera");
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            collision.gameObject.transform.position = spawnTeleport.gameObject.transform.position;
        }
    }
}
```

Этот код должен быть добавлен в скрипт Teleport. Он будет выполняться один раз при старте игры. Если какой-то из компонентов не найден, то в консоль выведется сообщение об ошибке. Это поможет определить, в чем именно заключается проблема.

---

Если вы добавили персонажу спрайт через `GameObject > 2D Object > Sprites > Square`, то у персонажа уже должен быть компонент `SpriteRenderer`. Этот компонент отвечает за отображение спрайта персонажа на сцене. Поэтому, если у вашего персонажа уже есть этот компонент, то нет необходимости его изменять.

Однако, важно проверить, что у компонента `SpriteRenderer` установлено свойство `enabled` в `true`. Это необходимо, чтобы спрайт персонажа отображался на сцене. Для этого вы можете добавить следующий код в функцию `Start`:

```
// Проверяем, что у персонажа компонент SpriteRenderer установлен в true
if (!GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled)
{
    Debug.LogError("У персонажа компонент SpriteRenderer установлен в false");
}
```

Если у компонента SpriteRenderer установлено свойство enabled в false, то спрайт персонажа не будет отображаться на сцене. Чтобы исправить эту проблему, вы можете установить свойство enabled в true. Для этого вы можете использовать следующий код:

```
GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = true;
```

В этом случае спрайт персонажа будет отображаться на сцене.

---

Если вы уже устранили все ошибки, но персонаж по-прежнему пропадает при вхождении в коллайдер телепорта, то стоит проверить следующие вещи:

1. Убедитесь, что у объекта спавна телепорта установлена правильная позиция. Для этого вы можете вручную изменить позицию объекта спавна телепорта в Unity, либо указать нужную позицию в коде.
2. Проверьте, что у персонажа и объекта спавна телепорта установлены нужные теги. В коде вы указываете, что персонаж должен иметь тег "Player", поэтому убедитесь, что у персонажа установлен этот тег.
3. Проверьте, что у персонажа и объекта спавна телепорта установлены нужные компоненты. В коде вы указываете, что у объекта спавна телепорта должен быть компонент Transform, поэтому убедитесь, что у объекта спавна телепорта установлен этот компонент.
4. Проверьте, что коллайдер телепорта работает правильно. Убедитесь, что у коллайдера телепорта установлены нужные настройки, и что он работает как нужно.

Если вы выполните эти шаги, то скорее всего сможете решить проблему с отсутствующим персонажем.

---

Если у вас не отображаются спрайты телепортов, то стоит проверить следующие вещи:

1. Убедитесь, что у телепортов установлен компонент SpriteRenderer. Этот компонент отвечает за отображение спрайта на сцене.
2. Убедитесь, что у компонента SpriteRenderer установлено свойство enabled в true. Это необходимо, чтобы спрайт телепорта отображался на сцене.
3. Убедитесь, что у компонента SpriteRenderer указан правильный спрайт. Для этого вы можете вручную указать спрайт в поле Sprite компонента SpriteRenderer, либо указать спрайт в коде.
4. Убедитесь, что у телепортов установлены нужные настройки рендеринга. В частности, убедитесь, что у телепортов установлен слой, который отображается на сцене.

Comment: А что если я добавил персонажу спрайт через GameObject>2D Object> Sprites >Sqaure? Обязательно изменять?

Comment: Обновил ответ на вопрос

Comment: Всё, пофиксил все ошибки, но всё равно, при вхождении персонаж пропадает

Comment: Кстати, почему-то спрайты телепортов не отображаются, хоть я их и поставил

Comment: Проверьте ещё раз

Comment: Спасибо большое, оказалось, что проблема как раз таки в позиции телепортов, а точнее в координате Z. У персонажа она была выше фона, а у телепортов ниже, по-этому фон просто перекрывал персонажа. Ещё раз спасибо, и с наступившим новым годом вас!